# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CCTMXTiledMap*' from 'CCTMXLayer*'

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, warnings

Im getting two warnings when i build and run my code. The App still works and it doesn't crash but I don't understand why I'm getting the two warnings. The first warning is listed in the title and the second warning states "Method '-checkForAndResolveCollisions' not found.

```
-(id) init
{

if( (self=[super init]) ) {

    CCLayerColor *blueSky = [[CCLayerColor alloc] initWithColor:ccc4(100, 100, 250, 255)];
    [self addChild:blueSky];

    map = [[CCTMXTiledMap alloc] initWithTMXFile:@"level1.tmx"];
    [self addChild:map];

    player = [[Player alloc] initWithFile:@"koalio_stand.png"];
    player.position = ccp(100, 50);
    [map addChild:player z:15];

    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

    walls = [map layerNamed:@"walls"]; *

}
return self;

}

-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
[player update:dt];

[self checkForAndResolveCollisions:player]; **
}
```

Title warning is shown on the line with *
The method not found warning is shown on the line with **

Comment: I've fixed the incompatible pointer type issue but I'm still stumped on the method issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you simply need to add the method declaration for "`checkForAndResolveCollisions:`" to that class .h / @interface file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! How would I go about declaring the method? Im just not sure how to declare something of that sort :(

Comment: is "`checkForAndResolveCollisions`" (the method & it's code) in that .m file?  what does the declaration look like?

Comment: The code for the method is in the .m file but there is no declaration in the .h file under the @interface section. I tried to declare it but I don't think I'm declaring it right as when I do it the code doesn't compile and run because it gives me an error

Comment: if you're not declaring it right, post another question on [so] and I'll watch for it and if I catch it first, I'll answer it for you.  Make sure to show the code (or at least the function declarations).